how to merge 2 files if the data is matching between 2 files
I have the below input files and once matched trying to print the contents from both files.
file1:
7451,0831,N,L
6723,879,K,L

File2:
7451,0831,XC,N,,224,
6482,1234,XC,P,1,234

file2 might have different number of records, file1 is constant.
Output:
7451,0831,N,L,7451,0831,XC,N,,224,

I tried the below awk command but seems to print only the file2 matching record
awk -F ',' 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2];next} ($1,$2) in a { print a[$1],a[$2],$0]' \
    file1 file2


Record #1 of file2 has 7 fields, while record #2 has 6 fields, shall we assume every row may have a different number of fields? What about file1?

yes file2 might have different number of records, file1 is constant

Using any awk and assuming file1 isn't so huge that it can't fit in memory:
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    { key = $1 FS $2 }
    NR==FNR { a[key]=$0; next }
    key in a { print a[key], $0 }
' file1 file2
7451,0831,N,L,7451,0831,XC,N,,224,

I'm using a variable key above to avoid repeating which 2 fields are used for the join, if you don't mind repeating them you could just specify them at every step:
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    NR==FNR { a[$1,$2]=$0; next }
    ($1,$2) in a { print a[$1,$2], $0 }
' file1 file2
7451,0831,N,L,7451,0831,XC,N,,224,


If you didn't need to repeat the key before file2's fields, it would have been much simpler:
join -t, <(LC_COLLATE=C sort file1) <(LC_COLLATE=C sort file2)

However since you need to repeat the key before file2's fields, you're forced to specify a custom output format for join, which requires listing the required fields from each file, which in turn requires knowing how many fields to include from file1 / file2.
Since the number of fields varies across file2's records, you'll need to include a number of fields equal to the number of fields in the record with the most fields in file2 in join's output format string for this to work.
Using Awk and a clever method (if I say so myself) to auto-generate the list of fields to include from file2, you could do:
nf2=$(awk -F, '{NF>mnf && mnf=NF} END {print mnf}' file2)
f2of=( 2.{1..${nf2}} )
join -t, -o 1.{1..4} ${f2of[@]} <(LC_COLLATE=C sort file1) <(LC_COLLATE=C sort file2)


The Awk command will output the number of fields in the record with the most fields in file2
f2of=( 2.{1..${nf2}} ) will auto-generate the list of fields to include from file2, by expanding nf2 to 2.1 2.2 2.3 ... 2.nf2

% cat file1
6723,879,K,L
7451,0831,N,L
% cat file2
7451,0831,XC,N,,224,
6482,1234,XC,P,1,234
% nf2=$(awk -F, '{NF>mnf && mnf=NF} END {print mnf}' file2)
f2of=( 2.{1..${nf2}} )
join -t, -o 1.{1..4} ${f2of[@]} <(LC_COLLATE=C sort file1) <(LC_COLLATE=C sort file2)
7451,0831,N,L,7451,0831,XC,N,,224,


$ join -t ',' file1 file2
7451,0831,N,L,0831,XC,N,,224,


Assuming the files are sorted. Try and swap the rows in file1. Normally you'd sort files before using them with join, using the C collation: join -t ',' <(LC_COLLATE=C sort file1) <(LC_COLLATE=C sort file2)

Also the output doesn't match, You'll need to use -o. join -t, -o 1.{1..4} 2.{1..7} <(LC_COLLATE=C sort in1) <(LC_COLLATE=C sort in2) 

Yes, true. The files have to be sorted before you can join them.

And OP's requirement is to repeat file1/2's key before file2's fields, currently your command doesn't do that, if you cared to at least point out these two things in your answer I would remove my downvote, but also note that file2's length (in term of fields) is not fixed, so there's no easy solution using join unfortunately
